# The variation of the flux of the linkage for the asymptotically flat spacetime

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, energy-conservation, gravitational-waves, asymptotics

The concept of the linkage for the asymptotically flat spacetime is defined and dicussed in [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.524987) by Geroch and Winicour. This is a nice paper, but I came across one problem.

The linkage is an integral which gives the energy, the momentum and the angular momentum of an asymptotically flat spacetime. Any arbitrary spacetime does not in general possess any Killing vector fields, but an asymptotically flat spacetime have the socalled asymptotic symmetries BMS symmetries, because as one recedes from the center of the spacetime, one finds out that the curvature becomes smaller and smaller and  the spacetime looks more and more like a Minkowski one.

In the conformal completion description of the asymptotically flat spacetime, a conformal factor $\Omega$ is introduced which vanishes at the null infinity $\mathscr I$. The infinitesimal asymptotical symmetry is a vector field $\xi^a$ which acts on the spacetime metric $\tilde g_{ab}$ in the following way,

$$\Omega^2\mathscr L_\xi\tilde g_{ab}=\mathscr L_\xi g_{ab}-2Kg_{ab}$$

approaches zero as the null infinity $\mathscr I$ is approached. Here, $g_{ab}=\Omega^2\tilde g_{ab}$ is the conformal metric, and $K=\xi^an_a/\Omega$. This behavior can be described by introducing a rank-2 tensor field $X_{ab}$ which can be smoothly extended to $\mathscr I$, so that

$$\Omega^2\mathscr L_\xi \tilde g_{ab}=2\Omega X_{ab}\Rightarrow \nabla_{(a}\xi_{b)}=Kg_{ab}+\Omega X_{ab}$$

Here, the covariant derivative $\nabla_a$ is compatible with $g_{ab}$ and the indices are raised and lowered by $g_{ab}$ and its inverse. So $X_{ab}$ measures the failure of $\xi^a$ being a conformal Killing vector field for $g_{ab}$.

$\xi^a$ is not exactally a Killing vector, but asymptotically it is. So the linkage is proposed to be the generalization of the Komar integral, reexpressed in terms of the quanties related to the unphysical metric $g_{ab}$,

$$L=\int_S\epsilon_{abcd}\nabla^c(\Omega^{-2}\xi^d)dS^{ab}$$

where $S$ is a topological 2-sphere at $\mathscr I$, $dS_{ab}$ is its area element. One can easily check this expression starting the usual Komar integral.

In a generic asymptotically flat spacetime, there can be gravitational waves escaping from $\mathscr I$. So $L$ will not be a constant in the retarded time. If one chooses a different $S'$, then one finds out that $L'-L$ is not vanishing in general. The difference is $L'-L=\int_BF(X)\bar\epsilon_{abc}$, and the flux $F(X)$ is

$$F(X)=-\nabla^a\nabla^bX_{ab}+3\nabla^aX_a+\frac{3}{4}\nabla_a\nabla^aX+\frac{1}{24}RX$$

where $X_a=X_{ab}n^b/\Omega$ with $n^a=\nabla^a\Omega$, $X=X^a_a$ and $R$ is the Ricci scalar for $g_{ab}$.

Then Eq. (32) is difficult to derive,

$$n^a\nabla_aF(Y)=-\Omega^{-1}C_{abcd}n^bn^dY^{ac}$$

Here, $Y_{ab}$ is a particular $X_{ab}$ such that the change in $g_{ab}$ is given by $\delta g_{ab}=2\Omega Y_{ab}$. The change in $g_{ab}$ is thought to be generated by an infinitesimal coordinate transformation.

The authors gave the hint to derive it. That is, one starts with the perturbed Einstein's equation in the vacuum, with the perturbation of the physical metric given by $\delta\tilde g_{ab}=2\Omega^{-1}Y_{ab}$. Then contract this equation by $n^an^b$ to give Eq. (32). I followed this suggestion but I did not get Eq. (32). In fact, if one carefully exames Eq. (32), one finds out that this equation involves the 3rd order derivatives, because on the left hand side, $F(Y)$ contains $\nabla^a\nabla^bY_{ab}$. But the linearised Einstein's equation involves the 2nd order derivatives at most. Then how could it be possible to obtain Eq. (32) from the perturbed Einstein's equation?

I need your help. Thank you!